# react render data array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, map-function

I have facing an issue in react js, i use array map function to render data on component but they show `last value` of data.

react component

```
  if (this.state.data
    && this.state.data.length
    )  
    {this.state.data.map(({ full_name }, i) => (
           name = (
          <p key={i}>{this.state.data[i].full_name }</p>
        )))
 }

return ( 
<div className="row">
  {names}
</div>
```

show `all values` of data but they show `last value`

names data

```
alex
john
smith //they show last value
```

what should i change in my code? 
anyone help me?

Comment: you're throwing the result of `.map()` away - you probably intended to capture that as `names`? Also, don't assign things inside a `.map()`, it already turns the source array into a target array of transformed data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const names =
 this.state.data.length > 0 &&
 this.state.data.map(name => <p key={name}>{name}</p>);

  return ( 
    <div className="row">
      {names}
    </div>
   );
```

Comment: not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6669995/majid-eltayeb)

Comment: If you're using `map`, you don't need to test `length`: `[]` turns into `[]`, and anything with data in it will get transformed. `const names = this.state.data.map(name => <p key={name}>{name}</p>);` is enough here.

Comment: I used .length to check if the state.data is getting filled by a callback function so this is just a check for not getting undefined if the call is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

edited based on comment feedback below

```
 const names = this.state.data.map((item) => (
          <p key={item}>{item.full_name }</p>
        ))
```

or

```
 const names = this.state.data.map(({full_name}) => (
          <p key={full_name}>{full_name}</p>
        ))
```

here's a sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wood-9jrib?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Presumably `this.state.data` is always an array (although it might be empty) so we don't need any of those extra checks. `const names = this.state.data.map((item, i) => <p key={item_full_name}>{item.full_name }</p>)` works fine. Also, _never use array position as key_, the whole point of the key is that it uniquely identifies real data for the purposes of DOM diffing. If you swap two elements in an array their index changes but the data is still the same: array position does not uniquely identify elements.

Comment: Hi mike, thanks a lot for the feedback. Some questions for you: 'Presumably this.state.data is always an array': it is safe to assume that? what if data is initialized as {} or null?  where does this key value come from `{item_full_name}`? Since `names` is immutable, doesn't that guarantee that assigned i to key is unique and consistent? appreciate your insight

Comment: here's an article for anyone else which fully explains mike's comment: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: then that would be a different error - as the person responsible for the code, initialise your state so that it stays predictable. Don't change types, keep things stable.